# How can I adjust the caption spacing between in-line subfigures?

Tags: spacing, subcaption

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{\lipsum[1]}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{\lipsum[1]}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: captions_too_close]

As you can see, there is no spacing between the captions of subfigures (a) and (b). How can I control the subfigure caption spacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width of the subcaptions and centre the subfigures  inside their columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}\centering
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{width=0.9\linewidth}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
 \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{\lipsum[1]}
        \end{subfigure}%
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
 \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{\lipsum[1]}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]